# Get the model name to implement a reusable method in AppModel in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

How can I get the current model name in `AppModel`?

I have this code to verify password and confirm password. But I would like to put it in `AppModelp`:

```
function isSameAs($check, $field) {
  if( $check === $this->data['User'][$field] ) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I am using CakePHP 2.

Comment: I don't know cakephp so I can't answer your question. But your code is really verbose. Instead of `if($check === $this->data['User'][$field]) { return true; } else { return false; }`, you can just do `return $check === $this->data['User'][$field];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are best to use `$this->alias` (see [API for model](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model)). Using @Ben Lee's suggestion, that would be:

```
function isSameAs($check, $field) {
    return $check === $this->data[$this->alias][$field];
}
```

Comment: and if that is actually supposed to be a validation rule, it should more likely be $check = array_shift($check) first.